# Inserting missing sequence into hourly data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a list of data that was compiled by taking a timestamp every 0.01 inches of rain accumulated. Because of this the data does not have the times in-between the recordings, when no precipitation was recorded. I figured out how to round the data to the nearest hour, however now I would like to fill in the hours that should say 0.00 with them.

I.e. My data looks like this:

10/11/2012  22:00 0.01

10/16/2012 2:00  0.01

10/16/2012 3:00  0.02

But I would like to add in the hours in-between that should have 0.00 associated with them. Because this should be one full year there should be 8760 entries in total.

I do not have kutools and was trying to use the attached VBA code which I found online (https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1283-excel-insert-missing-numbers-in-sequence.html), however it does not take into account the hourly pattern of the data and instead creates single days and sets the time to 0:00.

If anyone knows how to fix this or has another solution I would really appreciate it! Thank you in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlMFI.png)

Answer (score 0):

It helps to know that Excel records dates as real numbers where the integers are days and the fractions the part of the day.  In your code, where you are adding 1 to populate the next value, try adding 1/24 (ie one 24th of a day, or 1 hour).  I think this would be around line 20, which I'd change to `outArr(i + 1/24, 1) = i + num1` to see what would happen.  Similar changes are probably necessary on lines 22 and 24.

However, assuming your data points are in a different column to your date/time values, I'd suggest the method above the one on the instruction page you linked to would be easier.

Create a list of ALL hours for your year underneath the existing data using the same format, following the instruction in your [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1225411/autofill-excel-with-an-hourly-breakdown-for-an-extended-amount-of-time), then sort the full list (original data plus the new list of hours) and remove duplicates.

You should be left with a sorted list of all hours in your year, with data points for those hours that have them.  You haven't said whether you want the 0.00 value added to the data cell, but if you do, it's trivial to do this using excel's ISBLANK() formula in an IF() condition.

Comment: I agree I thought that the "sort/delete all duplicates" method would be easier too, however when I select both columns and go to delete the duplicates it deletes the cells that are associated with the data instead of the extra date, leaving me with no data. And then when I select only column A (the dates) and go to delete all duplicates, it does not move column B (the data) correctly to keep the correct date associated with the correct data, so that then all of my data points are skewed to the wrong date. Any suggestions on what I might be missing?

Comment: I was able to find another solution using the "=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)<COUNTIF(A:A,A1)" formula in a new column and then filtering and deleting the values that were marked true!

Comment: With the sort/delete method, you only select the column of timestamps.  When I run this, it deletes the duplicate timestamps that *don't* have a value in the adjacent column.  The only suggestion I can make as to why this isn't working is you need to use the 'Filter the list, in-place' option, instead of 'Copy to another location'.